# Renaming columns systematically

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, recode

Consider the two dataframe `df1`, `df2` that have different column names. I need to systematically change the column naming scheme to obtain the same as in `df_target`

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  a = 0,
  b = 0
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  A = 0,
  B = 0
)

df_target <- data.frame(
  one = 0,
  two = 0
)
```

My thought would be create a dictionary (or any other approach would be fine) similar to the `df_mapping`

```
df_mapping <- data.frame(
  first = c("a", "A", "one"),
  second = c("b", "B", "two")
)
```

that contains a mapping so that I can systematically change the names. I am looking for some way to obtain this.

Note that the columns in each dataframe might be in arbitrary order. There might be some names that are unique to `df1` and `df2` and are not in the mapping and should stay the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` approach with `rename_with` + `case_match`:

```r
library(dplyr)

# create a formula-list lookup table
lookup <- c(
  c("a", "A") ~ "one",
  c("b", "B") ~ "two"
)

list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2) %>%
  lapply(\(df) rename_with(df, ~ case_match(.x, !!!lookup, .default = .x), everything()))

# $df1
#   one two  c
# 1   0   0  0
# 
# $df2
#   one two
# 1   0   0
```

Comment: How could I handle the case that `df1` has an additional column named `c`. What I would like to happen here is that `c` stays `c`.

Comment: @LukasUnterschuetz You can set `.default` in `case_match`. See my update!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function:

```r
change_name <-
  function(data, nms){
  tmp <- nms[nms %in% names(data)]
  colnames(data)[colnames(data) %in% tmp] <- names(tmp)
  data
}
```

And apply to your list of dataframes. This will work even if you have other columns in your dataframe, but you should create first a named vector with the new and old names:

```r
nms <- c(one = "a", one = "A", two = "b", two = "B")
lapply(list(df1, df2), change_name, nms = nms)

[[1]]
  one two c
1   0   0 0

[[2]]
  one two
1   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
 v1 <- list("one" = "A", "two" = "B")
df1 %>%
  setNames(toupper(names(.))) %>% 
  rename(!!! v1)
```

-output

```
   one two
1   0   0
```

---

For two datasets

```
library(purrr)
map(list(df1, df2), ~ .x %>%
       setNames(toupper(names(.))) %>% 
  rename(!!! v1))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
  one two
1   0   0

[[2]]
  one two
1   0   0
```

Comment: I have dataframes of varying lenght (columwise) and not all variable names should be changed, only those that i declare a scheme for.

Comment: @LukasUnterschuetz I think your mapping data format is confusing